# Change image through add/remove class in Javascript. What about at initial page scroll =0?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, header, addclass

I'm currently trying to change my header logo when the user scrolls past the dark background to a lighter background. I got the add/remove class working, but right when the user loads the page the image doesn't show because it executes when the scroll is greater than 0 pixels scroll. How do I show the initial conditions from page load without the user having scrolled already?

```
$(function() {
  var header = $(".logo");
  var about = $(".angle").offset().top;;
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
       if (scroll >= about) {
          header.removeClass('lightLogo').addClass('darkLogo');
       } else {
          header.removeClass('darkLogo').addClass('lightLogo');
       }
    });   
});
```

Comment: Why not just put the class 'lightLogo' on your header in your HTML so it starts that way?

Comment: hmm, well i tried but then the light logo regardless if i add or remove the class it can't change to the new image.

Comment: If you just add the darkLogo class, you have a conflict with the lightLogo class, so whichever of the selectors has precedence will win. You can (1) take one class off when you add the other or (2) just use one class and toggle it, or (3) make the default be what is in lightLogo and just have one darkLogo class that overrides it.

Comment: hmm any code to help me override this?

Comment: I posted an answer with probably the simplest approach, which is just to add it initially via a classname. Let me know if that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest might be to just add the class initially, like so:

```
$(function() {
  var header = $(".logo").addClass('lightLogo');
  var about = $(".angle").offset().top;;
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
       if (scroll >= about) {
          header.removeClass('lightLogo').addClass('darkLogo');
       } else {
          header.removeClass('darkLogo').addClass('lightLogo');
       }
   });   
});
```

Now the header will start out with .lightLogo at page load.

Comment: Great! ahh, such a simple add. I'm new to javascript, but thank you for the help. A lot of my learning has come from logical additions, this one just went over me. Thank you!

Comment: I have another issue you might be able to help me with. I'm currently making the add/remove function work when the user scrolls past a certain div that is dependent on the window size they launch the page at. unfortunately if they resize the browser the point at which it add/removes isn't linked with the div anymore. They'd have to refresh the page for it to match. Is there anyway I can make this function recur no matter what the user does with the resize?

Comment: You can use the jQuery "on" instead of "scroll" to run your function for multiple events: $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {...

Comment: Great, do I need to change the rest of the function or just add that? I tried that and no luck on resizing and it adjusting.

Comment: You might need to move the calculation of "about" inside the event handler, as for a resize the key might be that its value has changed.